# Why does Rust use or require the "let" keyword when declaring a variable?

Tags: rust

I was interested in Rust, and so I started reading the Rust programming guide on the Rust website, and discovered that variables are declared with the following syntax:

```
let x: i32 = 5;
```

Which means assign the value integer 5 to the variable type integer 32 bit which shall be referred to by the notation `x` from this point onwards.

Why is the `let` keyword reequired? It seems redundant, what does it actually "do"?

I assume the compiler would be able to tell that the following is a variable (or const variable) declaration:

```
x: i32 = 5;
```

There doesn't appear to be a reason for a `let` keyword, but presumably there *is* a smart reason because Rust is focused on safety. So what is that reason?

---

Edit: Addition: As function arguments, the let keyword is not required. Here is an example:

```
fn add1(x: i32) -> i32
{
    x = x + 1
}
```

This seems a bit strange - this "looks like" a pass by reference because of the missing `let`. But it's not. It's a pass by value. (Or at least I think it is.) Is this a syntactic inconsistency?

---

As an aside, why is the ordering of the variable name and type different from other languages? For example, the syntax could have been:

```
i32 x = 5;
```

Put a colon in there if you prefer.

```
i32: x = 5;
```

- When programming you usually know what "type" of data you want before you think of a name for it. Maybe that's just something that comes from a C++ background, perhaps some think the other way around?

This brings me to another point; how can one declare a several variables of the same type in Rust? Such as:

```
let x, y, z: i32 = {4, 5, 5} // A guess of what this might look like?
```

Or is this just not allowed in Rust?

Comment: I don't get your point of your edit. In a function signature, the context tells us that we're declaring parameters and not assigning anything. And how you get the impression that anything happens by-reference, without any `&` or other indicator, is beyond me.

Comment: @delnan Read it carefully - I said that it isn't by reference, but it looks like it might be.

Comment: I understand that. I just don't get how it might look like it. There is nothing indicating that. As you note, the only difference is the absence of `let`, what does that have to do with by-value/by-reference?

Comment: The fact that `let` it missing makes it look (to me personally) like it's not the creation of a new variable. Therefore perhaps it is something else. Perhaps that something else is a reference? What else could it be?

Answer (score 42):

Rust has local type inference, so the type normally doesn’t need to be written; `let x = 5;` will suffice. `x = 5;` would be quite different, as it would not *declare* a variable `x`, and Rust very deliberately separates declaration and assignment.

It’s also actually `let PATTERN = EXPR;`, not just `let IDENT = EXPR;`, so removing the `let` keyword would cause grammatical ambiguity. A pattern could be `mut x` (making the variable binding mutable), it could be `(a, b)` signifying tuple unpacking, *&c.*

You only think `i32 x = 5;` makes sense because you’re used to languages like C++. Seriously, who came up with that idea? It makes more sense on purely philosophical grounds to have the type after the name than before, and having just the type to declare variables is silly too. All sorts of grammatical ambiguity there. Type inference, allowing you to omit the type altogether, is a much nicer approach all round.

Comment: Interesting points raised here - can you give an example of such an ambiguity? And to respond to paragraph 3, No, many years ago when I stopped using Basic and went to start programming in C, I liked that the "dim" keyword had disappeared because I didn't see any reason for it being there. I don't understand your point about philosophical grounds - I think it's perhaps personal preference whether you prefer type or identifier first? What's your philosophical argument for having the type after?

Comment: So, from a visual perspective, assigning a value to a type is less silly than i32 x = 5; ?

Comment: _"Who came up with that idea?"_ [Dennis Ritchie did](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html). _"Analogical reasoning led to a declaration syntax for names mirroring that of the expression syntax in which the names typically appear."_ In retrospect, it was an unfortunate move (because it removed all hope of context insensitivity from the language), but it probably seemed like a great idea at the time exactly on philosophical grounds ("how do you generalise type composition syntax?")

Comment: @Wtrmute: I’m finding that a bit hard to follow. Is the expression syntax it refers to “(int) foo”? If so that doesn’t seem like a very good mirror, so I’m wondering if it’s something else.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Ritchie's article (which I linked) explains this much better than a SO comment ever could, but it refers to the expressions with which one gets the primitive type out of the type of the variable. Ritchie gives examples, among which `int *api[10], (*pai)[10];` — in each case, the expressions `*api[0]` and `(*pai)[0]` yield exactly the primitve type `int`.

Answer (score 13):

First, parsing ambiguity. While it *may* be possible to parse such code (but only because `a < b > c` is already illegal as expression for a different reason), it would complicate all tooling and make parser performance (and error recovery) worse.

Second, type inference. Regardless of where the type is written, it can be omitted, so you need `let` or another marker to distinguish assignment from declaration. (You could technically use `let x = ...;` and `Type x = ...;` but why? It's not a type, it's the *absence* of a type.)

Third, generality. `let` works with any (irrefutable) pattern, including those that double as perfectly legal expressions: `StructLiteral { field: x, other_field: y }` and `Some(thing)`. This is a source of even more ambiguity, if not for the parser (it rejects `Some(a) = b` currently), then for humans.

Fourth, while *you* may be used to `type name`, there is a long tradition of `name: type`, and it's gaining mainstream traction without Rust's doing (e.g. in Scala).

Fifth, I dispute this:

> When programming you usually know what "type" of data you want before you think of a name for it.

Perhaps I know the general shape of the data (an integer, a string, an iterator, a set, etc.) but the exact type is often an implementation detail that comes second. This argument also falls apart in the face of type inference: How can leaving the type out be useful if that's what you are mostly thinking in? If on the other hand you're only talking about what you think of first while *writing* code, then the case is dismissed: Code is read far more often than it is written, and the order in which concepts are introduced need not (and often shouldn't) reflect the order in which they are conceived.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to say in the final paragraph. When I write programs, I know whether my data is an integer, a pointer, a floating point value, a char, a std::vector, etc, etc... I would probably say it's not possible to write code unless you know about what format your data is to be stored in. That's the whole point about programming - to manipulate data, so if you "don't know" what your data looks like then you'd better figure it out before you start typing!

Comment: @user3728501 I know what my data looks like. Fortunately, in that I am not fully constrained by the machine and can think more abstractly: I can know that something is an integer without already making up my mind whether it's `u32` or `u64`. I can know that I want to look up the users for all the user IDs without caring that the result type of `items.iter().map(User::lookup)` is `iter::Map<slice::Iter<u32>, fn(u32) -> User>`. And even if I need to know these things at some point, I don't need to know *at all times* and push it into the face of every reader.

Comment: I would suggest that is poor practice - you will make mistakes if you're not aware at all times what your data is stored as and how it will behave.

Comment: @user3728501 So you are opposed to type inference as well?

Comment: @user3728501 Regardless, we are now arguing about the thought process of the author when writing code. A more important point, to me, is whether it makes sense to the *reader*. Is "Here's the amount of space to allocate, as `usize`" really more sensibe, semantically, then "Here's some `usize` that stores the amount of space to allocate"?

Comment: Type inference could be useful if there is no ambiguity. But generally I think programming languages are better without it. Without inference you have to be specific, and know exactly what you are doing - so I would probably say yes, although I don't really have a strong opinion about it, I think no type inference is slightly better than having type inference.

Comment: Why are you only interested in the reader? Of what use is code which can be read easily and not written easily? A person isn't useful as a translator if they can read French but not speak or write it.

Comment: Surely `int a = 32` is easier to read and write than `a int = 32`. The second makes _no sense what so ever_ because it looks like you are assigning the value `32` to `int` - why? Because `int` is the other side of the `=` sign, of course... The second only makes some sense if you add a colon: (Or other symbol) eg: `a: int = 32`, because the colon makes it look like you are adding some extra information there.

Comment: @user3728501 Of course writing needs to be possible. But we're talking about (what you perceive to be) a slight loss in write-ability, for a slight win in readability. The fact that it will be read more often than written makes this a good trade off. RE: Last comment: But we *do* add the colon, and it even has many additional benefits (as explained in this answer). So what's your point here? And again, consider that the by far most common variable declaration in Rust is `let name = value;` with no type mentioned.

Comment: Why would any code be read more often than it is written or modified? I would suggest the opposite is true - I modify my code all the time - I hardly ever "read it", and few others read it in my line of work. Even as a software developer, I would suggest unless you are in a specific roll writing generic code, you code will be written many more times than being read.

Comment: @user3728501 This is turning into a discussion that exceeds the scope of a comment chain (and Stack Overflow in general), so I'll refer you to Google to find some of the many essays arguing that "code is read more often than it is written". I have neither the time nor the space to reproduce all the arguments here.

Comment: There are essays on such a topic? Please show me

Comment: More like blog posts, I suppose. Google finds plenty of support for the position in any case. It appears your line of work is simply very unusual.

Answer (score 9):

It significantly simplifies the grammar. Remember, there's a full pattern on the left hand side, it's not actually `let var` it's `let pattern`.

> how can one declare a several variables of the same type in Rust?

This is a completely different question, but there's no direct way to do this, no, at least not in the way you're thinking of. You can

```
let (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3);
```

But they don't *have* to be of the same type, this is a destructuring pattern in action.