# How do I initialize variable with a enum type in rust?

Tags: rust, enums

for example ,

```
enum People {
    Bad,
    Good,
}
```

I would like to initialize a variable with enum type,
I would then have if statement that assign enum value to variable,
And  I would like to use variable like:

```
fn main(){
    People he;
    if sth {
         he = People::Good;
    }else{
         he = People::Bad;
    }
    dosth(&he);
}
```

I looked at the docs but cant figure out how to.

Comment: Your syntax is not valid Rust.

Comment: I am inclined to say that these two questions answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180684/why-does-rust-bother-with-let https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73432621/how-to-declare-a-variable-but-not-assign-it

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger I saw the second, but don't think this is a duplicate of either. The real question is what we should do with users that clearly didn't even try to learn the language. I'd like to close this question, but I can't find a valid reason.

Comment: Remember, in Rust `if` can return a value, so `he = if ...` is valid code.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably trying to write:

```rust
enum People {
    Bad,
    Good,
}

fn dosth(p: &People) {}

fn main() {
    let he;
    if true {
        he = People::Good;
    } else {
        he = People::Bad;
    }
    dosth(&he);
}
```

Rust uses the keyword `let` to define a variable. You **can** assign it a type, like `let he: People;`, but usually Rust is able to figure out the type by itself. Rust is very strongly typed, if it can't figure out the type, it will give you a compiler error.